# How to create a author's box in home page WordPress with Loop Grid Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to put a box of the top authors on the main page of my site with the Elementor Loop Grid plugin, which includes the following information:
1- Avatar picture
2- Name and family's author
3- The link to view all the author's articles
4- I have the last post title sent by the same author.
Also, I don't want the authors to be repetitive and I want only one box for each author and the above information is displayed in it.
Thank you for helping me. Just like the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVoIQ.png)

made this box myself, but unfortunately, my problem is that the authors are repeated and I want only one box from each author

```
<?php
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;
    
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");
    
    foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
    echo $author->ID;
    echo "\">";
    echo get_avatar($author->ID);
    echo "</a>";
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
    echo $author->ID;
    echo "\">";
    the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<div>';
    echo "</li>";
    }
    }
    
    add_shortcode('author', 'contributors');
    ?>
```

this code, preview avatar image and display name of each author but i can't preview last post title. :(

Answer (score 0):

My friends, I used this code and my problem was solved. I wanted to share with you. good luck.

```
    <?php
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");


foreach($authors as $author) {
$getPosts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "author"         => $author->ID, 
        "posts_per_page" => 1,  
    )
);    
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
echo $author->ID;
echo "\">";
echo get_avatar($author->ID);
echo "</a>";
echo '<div>';
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
echo $author->ID;
echo "\">";
the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo '<div>';
if($getPosts->have_posts()) {
    while($getPosts->have_posts()) {
        $getPosts->the_post();
        echo "<h2 class=\"post-title\"><a href=\"" . get_the_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>";
    }
}
echo "</li>";
}
}

add_shortcode('author', 'contributors');
?>
```

To use it, just create a file in the main path of your template called custom-shortcode.php and put this code inside it. Now you can display this box anywhere in the template with the shortcode [author].